# Saving files in MAUI

Tags: maui, maui-blazor, maui-windows

I'm writing a text editor in MAUI and encountered a problem that when executing this code (on Windows 10), the error "Exception raised: "System.UnauthorizedAccessException" in System.Private.CoreLib.dll". Tried googling how to allow the application to access the file system, but in vain

```
private async Task HandleSaveClick()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileContent) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
    {
        var fileData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileContent);
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAUI's developer team recently launched the official file storage API, which you could refer to [FileSaver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/essentials/file-saver?tabs=android) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the details about the file path? This error means the file path  you are trying to access is denied by the system. I have created a sample to save the file in the Folder metioned in the official document about the [Maui File System Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=windows).

```
using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "Test.txt"), FileMode.Create))
{
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is content");
    await filestream.WriteAsync(data,0,data.Length);
}
```

And the file will be saved into the **FileSystem.CacheDirectory**.

Comment: the file is chosen by the user.

Comment: https://github.com/Genolium/LiveCode/blob/master/LiveCode/Pages/FetchData.razor

Comment: You can try to test with my code to check if the cause is the file path or not. @IlyaVasunin

Comment: Well you just made a rewrite of what I had written in my post. Literally the same code

Comment: This code can run successfully in my project.